# How to get azimuth angle at the same time of getting accelerometer measure!ORIENTATION vs ACCELEROMETER

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, android-sensors

I'm doing this application that works like a pedometer counting steps, but I want it to show orientation for each step.

What i'm doing is registering two event listeners and than for each `onsensorchanged` event I'm picking up the values of the `sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` to get the azimuth angle, and of the `sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, where I see if a step is given or not.

At this time I'm getting the values correctly but I want to peak only the azimuth angla when the step count is done!How do I do this ?

I'm supposing that it will be done inside the `OnSensorChanged` method, but I'm not getting an idea on how to just call Orientation sensor, when Accelerometer Sensor is activated and a step is count..

Looking inside the code it will be something like this:
after registering the two listeners, `ACCELEROMETER` and `ORIENTATION`

```
OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if((event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER))

    accValues=event.values;

    // NOW get the orientation azimuth value at this time..
    orientationValues=event.values;
}
```

Hope that someone can clarify me on this..

Answer (score 2):

hey if  you want the azimuthal angle you can get it using the **ACCELEROMETER** and **MAGNETOMETER** sensors. First get the accelerometer data  and the magnetometer data .Next use **SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rotation_data, Inclination_data, acc_data, mag_data)** function. you have to give **acc_data** and **mag_data** as input and you get **Rotation_data** and **Inclination_data** as output. Just pass them as empty arrays initially. once you have get the **Rotation_data** use **SensorManager.getOrientation(Rotation_data, angles)** . **angles** is an array you get as output.Pass it also as an empty array initially. after the function call you get **angles[0]** as azimuthal,**angles[1]** is pitch and **angles[3]** is roll. All the arrays used are a single dimension array of 3 elements.